# How can I call Python from RPGLE and return a value?

Tags: python, rpgle

My team is *very* new to using Python, and we're trying to call it from our native programming language- RPGLE (free). We've found several examples of calling it using the command line, but nothing from within RPG code that's not just running a command.

The issue with calling Python via command is that we can't return a value to the calling RPG program. Does anyone know if this is possible, and how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1012360) might help.

Answer (score 2):

I won't say it's impossible, but a better idea is to have the python code run as a web service.

It's easy to call a web service from RPG using Scott Klement's [HTTP API](http://www.scottklement.com/httpapi/) or various other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the Python program is stored on IBM i.. right?

In any case, anyway, you have at least 3 options to call it:

1) Call the Python program using Qshell, [HERE AN OFFICIAL EXAMPLE](http://%20%20%20%20http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1012360)

2) Using the UNIXCMD tool, you can find it [HERE the official link](http://www.scottklement.com/unixcmd/)

3) Using a SRVPGM (someone also tell you)